# Detect only thicker horizontal straight lines in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, background, lines

Is there any algorithm in opencv to detect only thicker horizontal lines (straight lines) which are thicker than a given threshold in opencv. The thickness of the detected lines should exceed that given value. Normally in houghLines function there is no parameter to give a threshold thickness. [anyway my purpose is to detect all the background lines (white spaces exceeding certain height and width) in a document article and get the average thickness of those detected lines. If more clarified my ultimate purpose is to calculate the average distance between text lines in a document]

Comment: just out of curiosity, you were working on horizontal projections. It seems the right way to go here (for your final purpose). What problems you had?

Comment: No miki, I cannot use horizontal projection. The text lines in the sample documents I have to use are not aligned on a same horizontal line if consider different columns. So that approach is impossible. I hope u can get it.

Comment: Got it. However, you usually deal with this first separating columns (with vertical projections) and then working on each column with horizontal projections. This is a simplification of the general [XY-cut algorithm](http://www.haralick.org/conferences/71280952.pdf)

Comment: use erosion or downsampling of the image

Comment: @Miki By doing so, when the separation of column phase is not accurate, then the final results too are faulty. Column separation is also not easy by vertical projections as columns are not so uniformly organized in the page structure if taken the whole page. And deciding a common threshold value to separate columns for all different types of pages is impossible(I don't know how to do that). So that is why I decided to follow the mentioned approach in the question.

Comment: That's why you usually go with XY-cut, and not just with projections.

Comment: @Miki As I have understood what x-y cut is, my previous comment shows the problems emerged via that algorithm. U have briefed wht x-y cut is actually ("deal with this first separating columns (with vertical projections) and then working on each column with horizontal projections. This is a simplification of the general XY-cut algorithm"). So if we can use it for my purpose what is the solution for above problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood correctly. I'll try to explain. In general, for printed documents, you apply recursive XYcut algorithm (probably the confusion is because I omitted "recursive" earlier). If you look at the picture in the paper I posted earlier, that should clarify how to deal with "non uniformly organized" text blocks.

Answer (score 3):

The standard method to achieve this is *erosion*. If you eat away the outer 5 pixels of all objects, and you still have a line left, then the line previously was at least 11 pixels wide.

Comment: Can u please describe your answer?

Comment: or downsample the image which might even lead to cheaper computation

Comment: Can this approach determine the width of original line? I think this is similar to Jublee's answer. Anyway I don't see that I can extract only the straight lines here. All the rounded lines too will be detected. (sorry if u understood that 'lines' refers to also rounded lines too. I will update the question to mean straight lines only)

Comment: If you eat away 5 pixels on both sides, and there's still a line left, then you know the original line was _at least_ 11 pixels wide. Whether you detect straight lines or cruved _edges_ depends on the next step.

Comment: So do u suggest to check eating away various number of pixels until there is only one pixel wide line left?

Answer (score 0):

Do a guess of how many pixels the thickest line you want to find will have . Erode all the remaining pixels from all other object . In that case you will be left with the few pixel of the thickest link.Then you can draw hough lines on that.

```
 bool done;
 do
{
  cv::morphologyEx(img, temp, cv::MORPH_OPEN, element);
  cv::bitwise_not(temp, temp);
  cv::bitwise_and(img, temp, temp);
  cv::bitwise_or(skel, temp, skel);
  cv::erode(img, img, element);

 double max;
 cv::minMaxLoc(img, 0, &max);
 done = (max == 0); // max cab be the threshold you want to use 
   } while (!done);
```

For more reading check morphological skeleton operations:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_skeletona

http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/
Hope it helps.- check this link it will help you understand what is being done.

Comment: Can u please explain what is done here and what is the output?

Comment: http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/  check this link it will help you understand what is being done.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked it. But actually that approach seems not giving what I want. Because by this, the final output will give only a thin line as it is already skeletonized. But I want to detect and extract the lines in thick state. I want to draw the detected thick lines in the same image or another image as in same thickness as in my original input file.

Comment: If you use this method  you will be identify  a particular  threshold at  which only thick lines you want remain skeletonized and all others thin lines removed . Use the same threshold to redraw the lines **eg:  line( frame, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 10, CV_AA);** in this function give the size of the line you want to draw .

Comment: So that threshold value is the thickness of all the lines drawn, which is not correct actually. Various lines would have various thicknesses exceeding the value of that threshold thickness. So in this way this approach won't draw the real thickness of the lines. (it is constant here)